# html parsing without using text.splitlines() custom split in lines using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have and html file and want to get the list of lines from it.

```html
<html><head></head><body>subject marks
    <div dir="ltr">marks<br/><br/><div class="gmail_quote"><div class="gmail_attr" dir="ltr">  Forwarded message  <br/>From: <strong class="gmail_sendername" dir="auto"></strong> <span dir="auto">&lt;<a href="mailto:"></a>&gt;</span><br/>Date: Wed, Nov3 at 1:11 PM<br/>Subject:Marks<br/>To: sk &lt;<a href="sh.com">sj@sh.com</a>&gt;, &lt;<a href="mailto:"></a>&gt;<br/></div><br/><br/><div dir="ltr">1)Physics 50<div> 2)Maths 46</div><div> 3)Chemistrry 42</div><div> 4)geography 49</div><div> 5)History 40</div> 7)English - 42<div><br/></div><div><div><div data-smartmail="gmail_signature" dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>REGARDS,<br/></b></span></font></div><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>AGR<br/></b></span></font></div><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>ljs</b></span></font></div><div dir="ltr"><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>988ss79808</b></span></font></div><div dir="ltr"><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>9226djgf8468</b></span></font><br/></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
    </div></div>
    
    <br/>
    <div></body></html>
```

I want to get the list of lines from it.
Please note: I want it to be a generic one since I want to extract lines even if there is a table in it. I will not split on some given tags like `<td>`, `<a>`.

In this subject 2 to subject 5 are in a nested div tags which is a child div of div having subject 1  and subject 6

If anyone could help in to parse this into lines, other than using `text.splitlines()` beacause that splits on all tags.

Output Expected is list of lines

My approach: I have used
"""

> for element in soup.find_all():
> if element.name not in ['tr', 'a']:
> element.append('\n')

"""

this gives subject 1 and 2 in a single line

Comment: What do you mean **list of lines**? Is it a `List<T_List>` (instance of a List object)? You also need to tell what your intention of using the list is for? What will be your scripting language? The drafting of question is very poor. Please amend it to bring clarity of your problem.

Comment: why not use an `ol` for a numbered list instead of divs?

Comment: list of lines I mean: list of text

Comment: So you are saying it's an instance of `List` Class.

Comment: yes like this : 
[subject marks,
marks,

Forwarded message,
From: <>,
Date: Wed, Nov3 at 1:11 PM,
Subject:Marks,
To: sk <sj@sh.com>, <>,


1)Physics 50,
2)Maths 46,
3)Chemistrry 42,
4)geography 49,
5)History 40,
7)English - 42,

REGARDS,
AGR,
ljs,
988ss79808,
9226djgf8468,
]

Comment: Is that actual code, or pseudo code? Don't make us guess, [edit] the question and tag it with the scripting or programming language that you are using. For now this can not be answered by anyone except by taking a wild guess.

Comment: it looks like Python code using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: yes, usnig beautiful soup. i have edited the question with language tag

Comment: @sameer Well actually, you edited the title, but not the tags. Those are very important and used by visitors to filter questions.

Comment: Oops i provide an answer using `regular expression`. Hope that is ok

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import re

def extract_lines(html):

  # Remove all whitespace between tags.
  html = re.sub(r">\s*<", "><", html)

  # Split the HTML string into lines.
  lines = html.splitlines()

  # Return a list of strings, each representing a line of text.
  return [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

The above code can be used like this

```
html = """
<html><head></head><body>subject marks
<div dir="ltr">marks<br/><br/><div class="gmail_quote"><div class="gmail_attr" dir="ltr">  Forwarded message  <br/>From: <strong class="gmail_sendername" dir="auto"></strong> <span dir="auto">&lt;<a href="mailto:"></a>&gt;</span><br/>Date: Wed, Nov3 at 1:11 PM<br/>Subject:Marks<br/>To: sk &lt;<a href="sh.com">sj@sh.com</a>&gt;, &lt;<a href="mailto:"></a>&gt;<br/></div><br/><br/><div dir="ltr">1)Physics 50<div> 2)Maths 46</div><div> 3)Chemistrry 42</div><div> 4)geography 49</div><div> 5)History 40</div> 7)English - 42<div><br/></div><div><div><div data-smartmail="gmail_signature" dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>REGARDS,<br/></b></span></font></div><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>AGR<br/></b></span></font></div><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>ljs</b></span></font></div><div dir="ltr"><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>988ss79808</b></span></font></div><div dir="ltr"><font size="2"><span style="color:rgb(0,0,255)"><b>9226djgf8468</b></span></font><br/></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</div></div>

<br/>
<div></body></html>
"""

lines = extract_lines(html)

print(lines)
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: splitlines separates each tag into different lines. In case of table, for a single row there will be multiple cells i.e. td. Using this code will result in all cells in different lines. but actually i want it to be rowwise

Comment: This is only a kickstart, there will be many variations to the input. Looking at output it generates, Try modifying the code for various criteria

Comment: yeah, I already tried this solution. Have already mentioned this in question itself.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a try with *BeautifoulSoup* `soup.get_text('\n')` and got this text result:

```
subject marks

marks
  Forwarded message
From:

<
>
Date: Wed, Nov3 at 1:11 PM
Subject:Marks
To: sk <
sj@sh.com
>, <
>
1)Physics 50
 2)Maths 46
 3)Chemistrry 42
 4)geography 49
 5)History 40
 7)English - 42
REGARDS,
AGR
ljs
988ss79808
9226djgf8468
```

As you can see, it's not what we would expect :-(

Then had a go with [*html2text*](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/),
running `html2text.html2text(html)` and wasn't totally happy:

```
subject marks

marks


Forwarded message
From: **** <[](mailto:)>
Date: Wed, Nov3 at 1:11 PM
Subject:Marks
To: sk <[sj@sh.com](sh.com)>, <[](mailto:)>




1)Physics 50

2)Maths 46

3)Chemistrry 42

4)geography 49

5)History 40

7)English - 42



 **REGARDS,
**

 **AGR
**

 **ljs**

 **988ss79808**

 **9226djgf8468**
```

The output seems better and looks like some kind of *MarkDown*
language as you can see the `**` for bold and the links
`[](mailto:)`. You could perhaps play with the
[*html2text* options](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text/blob/master/docs/usage.md#available-options) to get the desired output.

If not, I would consider using a better rendering engine such as
[*wkhtmltopdf*](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html) to create a PDF.

This PDF could then be converted back to text with
[*pdftotext*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext). I tried it out:

```bash
wkhtmltopdf source.html rendered.pdf
pdftotext -eol unix -layout -nopgbrk rendered.pdf rendered.txt
```

And got this text output:

```
subject marks
marks

Forwarded message
From: <>
Date: Wed, Nov3 at 1:11 PM
Subject:Marks
To: sk <sj@sh.com>, <>

1)Physics 50
2)Maths 46
3)Chemistrry 42
4)geography 49
5)History 40
7)English - 42

REGARDS,
AGR
ljs
988ss79808
9226djgf8468
```

In my opinion, it looks more like the real browser rendering.
You'll then be able to split lines.

Comment: @Raky Thanks. Well, the solution with *wkhtmltopdf* and *pdftotext* might be slower, but I'm rather convinced that a "real" rendering engine is needed to get a relatively correct output. Even the page size can change the output as text wrapping will depend on the page width, font size, etc.